# Deserialize binary encoded enum

Tags: rust, serde

I receive checksums as part of a binary protocol, which are represented in Rust in the following form:

```
enum Crc {
   Crc16([u8; 16])
   Crc32([u8; 32])
   Crc64([u8; 64])
}
```

I receive the enum variants encoded as byte arrays with the leading discriminant as u8 followed by the checksum byte arrays. As [`bincode`](https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode) cannot handle `u8` variant discriminants (see [internal discussion](https://github.com/bincode-org/bincode#why-does-bincode-not-respect-repru8)) in conjunction with other fixed size types and [`serde`](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/) has a [limit for arrays](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/631) of size 32, I would like to implement a `Deserializer` by myself. I know I have to manually deserialize the array using a [sequence visitor](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html#method.visit_seq) invoked with `Deserializer::deserialize_tuple`, but how can I handle the different variants?

Comment: I can of course match the first byte against hard coded discriminant values and hard code the size for each entry, but I hoped for a more generic way. ... And comment gone. :/

Comment: You can use crates for the array deserialization. For example this supports const generic arrays: https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/#large-and-const-generic-arrays

Comment: _"I can of course match the first byte against hard coded discriminant values"_ -- Considering that you're trying to deserialize a specific protocol, I'm not sure that matching against Rust enum discriminants "magically" is the right way to go. You almost certainly want to explicitly match on the bytes you're expecting to see in the protocol you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: @jonasbb I know serde_with, however, this would misinterpret the leading byte indicating the enum type.

Comment: @cdhowie I am not sure what do you mean with magically. There is one byte at the beginning of the array that indicates the crc type. As you can specify the discriminant values explicitly, I don't see any reason why not to use them.

Comment: @jonasbb Additionally serde_as seem to be not allowed on enum variants: https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/attr.serde_as.html

Comment: You apply it on the fields, not the variants: `Crc64(#[serde_as(as = "[_; 64]")] [u8; 64])`. There is no need to apply it to the variant.

Comment: Nice, didn't know this is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to implement a custom `Deserializer` for this. You can still use `bincode'`s `Deserializer` as long as you provide a custom `Deserialize` implementation to indicate the data you expect to receive.

Essentially, there are two separate pieces of data you expect: the variant discriminant (as a byte) and the checksum bytes (of varying size, depending on the variant). You can model this as a 2-tuple of data: `(discriminant: u8, checksum_bytes: [u8; LEN])` for some `LEN` that is either 16, 32, or 64.

We can treat each piece separately:

### Variant

You're right that `bincode` can't, by default, treat variant discriminants as `u8`s. But that doesn't mean we can't define a `Deserialize` implementation to treat them as `u8`s ourselves.

```rust
enum Variant {
    Crc16,
    Crc32,
    Crc64,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Variant {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct VariantVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for VariantVisitor {
            type Value = Variant;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("a single descriminant byte, either a 0, 1, or 2")
            }

            fn visit_u8<E>(self, byte: u8) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
            where
                E: de::Error,
            {
                match byte {
                    0 => Ok(Variant::Crc16),
                    1 => Ok(Variant::Crc32),
                    2 => Ok(Variant::Crc64),
                    _ => Err(E::invalid_value(Unexpected::Unsigned(byte.into()), &self)),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_u8(VariantVisitor)
    }
}
```

Now we have defined our own variant type (as opposed to the one derived by `serde_derive`) that deserializes a single byte as the variant. We can treat this `Variant` type as the first type in our 2-tuple.

### Checksum Bytes

As you mentioned, `serde` only provides implementations for arrays up to length 32. We can use those implementations for the 16 and 32 byte arrays, but we'll need to define our own type to deserialize an array of 64 bytes:

```rust
struct Crc64([u8; 64]);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Crc64 {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct Crc64Visitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for Crc64Visitor {
            type Value = Crc64;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("an array of length 64")
            }

            fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut value = [0; 64];
                for i in 0..64 {
                    value[i] = seq
                        .next_element()?
                        .ok_or(de::Error::invalid_length(i, &self))?;
                }
                Ok(Crc64(value))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_tuple(64, Crc64Visitor)
    }
}
```

This deserializes an array of 64 bytes into a `Crc64` `struct`. The method used is very similar to the one provided by `serde` for arrays of length 1-32.

### Putting it Together

Now we have every part we need: we can deserialize the variant discriminate, and we can deserialize the byte array for any of the sizes required. The last step is to tell `serde` that we expect a 2-tuple, and then deserializing that data in the visitor.

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Crc {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct CrcVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for CrcVisitor {
            type Value = Crc;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("a single descriminant byte followed by a checksum byte array")
            }

            fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                match seq
                    .next_element()?
                    .ok_or(de::Error::invalid_length(0, &self))?
                {
                    Variant::Crc16 => Ok(Crc::Crc16(
                        seq.next_element()?
                            .ok_or(de::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?,
                    )),
                    Variant::Crc32 => Ok(Crc::Crc32(
                        seq.next_element()?
                            .ok_or(de::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?,
                    )),
                    Variant::Crc64 => Ok(Crc::Crc64(
                        seq.next_element::<Crc64>()?
                            .ok_or(de::Error::invalid_length(1, &self))?
                            .0,
                    )),
                }
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_tuple(2, CrcVisitor)
    }
}
```

This first deserializes the variant into our `Variant` type, and then, based on the discriminant found, deserializes the remaining bytes into the correct length. Note that we had to use our `Crc64` type to deserialize the 64-byte array.

The full code is available at this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a034345c9ff2fc24a407476b5923cdae). Note that you won't actually be able to test this with `bincode` on the playground, because `bincode` is not available as a dependency there, but it should work correctly with `bincode` version 1.3.3, which is the version I tested on.

Comment: It somehow circumvents the idea of rust enums, which are designed to hold related data and it introduces the need to keep two data types in sync. However, for now this seems to be the best you can do. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about having the separate variant type. This is exactly how `serde` `Deserialization` is meant to work, and how it is implemented for other `enum`s. You can see a very similar looking type defined in `Result`'s `Deserialize` implementation: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde/src/de/impls.rs#L2559-L2562. The main difference here is we avoid using `deserialize_enum` so we can deserialize the discriminant as a `u8`.